# C# Cookies not refreshing cookies instantly

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm currently having an issue with cookies in my Web Application.

First of all, i created 2 generic methods into my controller to simplify my cookie manipulation. Here they are :

```
    public bool SetCookie<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        try
        {
            string str = Utils.JSONParser.Serialize(value);
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, Utils.JSONParser.Serialize(value))
            {
                HttpOnly = true
            };
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(365);
            Response.SetCookie(cookie);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public T GetCookie<T>(string key)
    {
        T obj;
        if (Request.Cookies[key] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(key);
            obj = Utils.JSONParser.Deserialize<T>(cookie.Value);
            return obj;
        }
        return (typeof(T) == typeof(int) ? (T)(object)-1 : default(T));
    }
```

Note that, theses methods are working perfectly with some "normal" use. (The Utils.JSONParser is a simple encapsulation of JavaScriptSerializer.

I'm having an issue by using this code :

```
 public ActionResult Index(int LineNumber = -1)
    {
        IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();

        if (LineNumber != -1)
            this.SetCookie("lineNumber", LineNumber);

        model.LineNumber = this.GetCookie<int>("lineNumber");
        ....
    }
```

Here, `LineNumber`'s value is for example 5, and the current cookie value is (for example) 20. So, here i wanna erase 20, and put 5 instead. But this isn't happening. I have to pass through this method 2 times (with 5 as parameter) to finally store 5 in the cookie value.

So my question is, is there a loading time to store a cookie ? Which would explain this ? Or am i simply missing something ?

Comment: The answer you might be looking for is here. http://forums.asp.net/post/2440644.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your `SetCookie` method changes the Response while your `GetCookie` method gets the value from your Request.  So only when you finish your entire request processing and then get a second request will the cookie set in the request be the cookie you set in the first response.

Comment: It seems a bit stupid now that you said it ... x). But I guess you're right ! Thank you very much man !

Comment: No worries, I made the exact same mistake once. ;)